# Would a compiler instantiate a new template function for ref parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following piece of code. Would the compiler generate 4 functions of operate() each with a different parameter or just one?

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void foo() const {}
};

template<typename T>
void operate(T obj)
{
    obj.foo();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass obj;
    MyClass& refObj = obj;
    const MyClass& constRefObj = obj;
    const MyClass constObj = obj;

    operate(obj);
    operate(refObj);
    operate(constRefObj);
    operate(constObj);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, this really depends on the compiler being used

Comment: note that this code only instantiates one function anyway (with `T = MyClass`)

Comment: @M.M You mean to say a copy constructor is invoked for every call? Even if i pass a const ref to obj as a param?  inconveinient!!

Comment: You have to tell the compiler you want your function to receive a reference if you want it to receive a reference:  `template <typename T> void operate(T&& obj)` will cause the type of `obj` to match the parameter: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74d82dc7288f99e1)

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi well that's what this code does... write different code if you want different behaviour. Use `&` or `&&` to pass by ref

Comment: @Miles Budnek, As per your example above, the above code would generate 2 functions with T = MyClass , T = const MyClass.

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi No, your original code only results in one instantiation with T = MyClass.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, You are right. As per the concept of overloading, having the function with T = MyClass and T = const MyClass would be redundant to the client.

Comment: Why don't you simply check the generated asm?  The [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) online compiler explorer makes that trivially easy..

Answer (score 1):

You can try for yourself. For `g++`, just run `g++ -S file.cpp` and see the result. For your code, `g++` generated a single function implementation and 4 calls that look as follows: `call _Z7operateI7MyClassEvT_`.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration

```
MyClass obj;
```

is where you actually create an object of type `MyClass`.

The second declaration

```
MyClass& refObj = obj;
```

just tells the compiler "when I use the name `refObj` I really mean `obj`". There is no new class instance created.

So both of these calls

```
operate(obj);
operate(refObj);
```

pass a copy of `obj` to the function. They are just using a different name for the same object. So surely they also call the same function.

Comment: You mean to say a copy constructor is invoked for every call? Even if i pass a const ref to obj as a param? That is inconveinient!!

Comment: You don't pass a const ref, you pass a `T`. The function declaration decides how the parameter is passed, not the call.